# How to invoke a const value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React.JS, I'm currently using it with Node and I'm having the following issue:

I'm using a button from **Material-UI** (Google's interface assets - buttons, menus, etc) and I have the button's styles defined inside a const that is ran through a function (because it's how it is declared in their own website, I'm not sure why I need to have a function instead of just calling the const).

What I'm doing is customizing the margin of the button I'm importing and setting the display to 'none' on the browser's pre-defined button so it disappears.

I inserted the const with the styles values inside a component called *HookApi.js* and this is its content:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      '& > *': {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
      },
    },
    input: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  }));

  export function UploadButtons() {
    const classes = useStyles();
}
```

And this is what I have inside my *Gallery.js* (which is replacing my *App.js* for testing purposes)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import HookApi from './constants/HookApi';
import { classes } from './constants/HookApi';




class Gallery extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }


    render() {



        return(

            <div className={classes.root}>
                <input
                accept="image/*"
                className={classes.input}
                id="contained-button-file"
                multiple
                type="file"
                />
                <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component="span">
                    Upload
                </Button>
                </label>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Gallery;
```

I'm not sure if I'm importing the const the wrong way in my *Gallery.js* but it gives me the following error when I'm rendering the page

['classes' is not exported from 'HookApi' - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeCaT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of exporting a `const`, you can try to export the function.

Gallery.js

```
import UploadButtons from './constants/HookApi';

render() {
    const {input} = this.props.UploadButtons();
    //...other logic
    (<input
       accept="image/*"
       className={input}
       id="contained-button-file"
       multiple
       type="file"
    />)
  }
}
```

Comment: I am exporting the function in my HookApi.js, but I don't know how to invoke it in my component - first off I'm importing the const instead of the function itself, in my Gallery.js, but it doesn't work either if I'm importing the function.

Comment: ```this.props.UploadButtons()``` is invoking the function. Your function returns a object, I destructure the object and get the ```input```. You can try to ```console.log()``` in the function, see whether it has been called. Also, check your css, make sure they are correct